# Use System Images in C#

Tags: c#

I am creating a custom messagebox. How can I use system pictures such as `Error`, `Information`, `Warning` and etc, which I see in windows `MessageBox`? I want to access them directly!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Take a look at `System.Drawing.SystemIcons`. You should find them there.

Then set your `PictureBox` (assuming Winforms here) like this:

```
PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Warning.ToBitmap();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the messagebox class a little further. You can specify a "MessageBoxIcon" when calling the method.

There are some good examples on how to acheive this here:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/messagebox-show

Comment: He said he was creating a custom MessageBox, but yeah, in any other case that would work :)

Comment: Ahh okay. See the term "custom messagebox" says to me that he was displaying a messagebox with a custom message, not that he was creating a winform as a messagebox. Oh well, there's two answers here now that should cover both instances :)

Answer (score 0):

You can draw the System icons in your custom MessageBox by handling the Paint event, e.g.

```
void MyMessageBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawIcon(SystemIcons.Warning, 16, 16);
}
```